# Unable to upload and send attachment using PHPMailer

Tags: email, phpmailer, email-attachments

Hello everyone, I am really stuck at this. I try to insert 1 field into one contact form (which I got from bootstrapious site) to upload attachment and send email. The field on the contact form will redirect to a php page (join.php). But somehow, mail can be send but no attachment found. Below is the php code.

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
// require 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';

$fromEmail = 'support@test.com';
$fromName = 'My Support';

$sendToEmail = 'test@gmail.com';
$sendToName = 'Test';

$subject = 'New message from contact form';

$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message');

$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, we will get back to you soon!';

$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

try
{

    if(count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Form is empty');

    $emailTextHtml = "<h1>You have a new message from your contact form</h1><hr>";
    $emailTextHtml .= "<table>";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailTextHtml .= "<tr><th>$fields[$key]</th><td>$value</td></tr>";
        }
    }
    $emailTextHtml .= "</table><hr>";
    $emailTextHtml .= "<p>Best Regards,<br>Support Team</p>";

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Port     = 587;  
    $mail->Username = "support@test.com";
    $mail->Password = "test123";
    $mail->Host     = "test.net";
    $mail->Mailer   = "smtp";
    $mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);
    $mail->addAddress($sendToEmail, $sendToName); 


    if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']))
    {
        $path = "/home/mtelesol/public_html/upload/";
        $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
            echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']). 
            " has been uploaded";
    }   
    else
    {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
    }


    $mail->addAttachment($path);

    $mail->addReplyTo($from);

    $mail->isHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = $subject;

    $mail->msgHTML($emailTextHtml); 


    if(!$mail->send()) {
        throw new \Exception('Message could not be sent.' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
    }

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $e->getMessage());
}


if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

and below is html code:

```
 <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="join.php" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        <div class="messages"></div>

                        <div class="controls">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_name">Firstname *</label>
                                        <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your firstname *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_lastname">Lastname *</label>
                                        <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your lastname *" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                                        <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_phone">Phone</label>
                                        <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your phone">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Attachment</label>
                            <input type="file" name="uploaded_file">
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
                                        <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message for me *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please,leave us a message."></textarea>
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <p class="text-muted"><strong>*</strong> These fields are required.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
```

I am newbie to php and web designing. Really hopes and appreciate anybody who can help me with this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Disable your redirects; they make things harder to debug. Do you get any error messages - your code should output something if your upload works or not.

Comment: If I took out the attachment field (html) and put it into single html page and link to php file for upload file only, it works. When I incorporate the upload html and php for the attachment into the contact form, it doesn't attach the file after I submit the form.

Comment: @Synchro No it doesn't output any error because the mail was sent successfully, just it does not attach the selected attachment from the file input.

Comment: Your code says whether it has attached the file or not. If you’re not seeing either of them you’ve probably not set the right mime type on your form.

Comment: You are setting the correct MIME type (enctype) so it's not that. I suggest you `var_dump($_FILES);` to be sure you're actually receiving the file. Also your code that checks the file path tries to add the attachment *even if the validation of the upload fails*, so you should fix that. Separately, you also need to learn how to use the `switch` statement in PHP. Is there any particular reason you're using an old version of PHPMailer?